# Slow rendering of data in Google Chrome after intalling SSL certificate on server

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I have a .NET C# program rendering on IIS web server. After adding SSL certificate to the server the program takes up to 5 minutes to respond to my request, only in Google Chrome. If I use the old HTTP URL everything is normal and the page is loaded after 33 sec. Does anyone have a suggestion on what causes this slow rendering of HTTPS web-page in Google Chrome?

Answer (score -1):

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly clear all the chrome's cache and update the chrome to the newest version. About how to troubleshoot google chrome's performance issue, you could refer to this [article](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9025467?hl=en).

If this doesn't solve your issue,  I suggest you could try to use chrome F12 develop tool to check what has happened when you send the request to the server. More details about how to use it, you  could refer to this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay. Unfortunately this does not work and I still have the same problem. It might have something to do with the encryption. But I can not figure it out.